# Getting bad request (400) when sending xml to REST service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest

I'm trying to use REST service with XML for the first time, and I'm keep getting error 400 (bad request).
Here is my code:

I have the following class that represents the xml structure:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")]
public class GetLicenseParams
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public GetLicenseParams() { }

    public GetLicenseParams(string filePath)
    {
        FilePath = filePath;
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the method:

```
protected void btnGetLicense_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MentorGraphicsAgent agent = new MentorGraphicsAgent();
    ltrLicences.Text = agent.GetLicense(new GetLicenseParams("MyFilePath"));
}
```

This is the `GetLicense` method:

```
public string GetLicense(GetLicenseParams @param)
{
    string requestUrl = string.Format("{0}GetLicense", "serviceurl", @param);
    return InvokePostRequest(requestUrl, @param);
}
```

And here is how I invoke the request and where I'm getting the error 400:

```
protected string InvokePostRequest(string requestUrl, GetLicenseParams @params)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-16";

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetLicenseParams));
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, @params);
        var xml = stringWriter.ToString();

        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        HttpWebResponse resposne = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //Error 400 (bad request)
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resposne.GetResponseStream()))
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "https://Services.Orbotech.com", ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]
public interface IMentorGraphics
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetLicense", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string GetLicense(GetLicenseParams @param);
}
```

And finaly, this is the service implementation:

```
public string GetLicense(GetLicenseParams @param)
    {...}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using WCF. Have you properly configured it to work as REST service?

Comment: I beleive I did, because it seems to work fine whrn I pass the XML hard coded, but when I use the XmlSerializer it get an error...

Comment: Can you add XML sample that worked for you?

Comment: Try using Fiddler and capture the XML that is being sent when you invoke the service from your app. Then compare it with the XML that works.

Comment: I tryied all that. here is the xml that is being generated by XmlSerializer: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><GetLicenseParams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><FilePath>\\nas-isl2\intefaceDev\</FilePath></GetLicenseParams>` and here is the xml that works: `<GetLicenseParams xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
//                                                            <FilePath>\\nas-isl2\interfaceDev\input.xml</FilePath>
//                                                       </GetLicenseParams>`